# Seeding datetime into database fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql

I am trying to seed a datetime into my PostgreSQL database:

```
6.times do |spots|
  title = "FUN STUFF NUMBER #{spots+1}"
  content = Faker::Lorem.sentence
  user_id = spots + 1
  spots = spots + 1
  starts_at = DateTime.now + 1

  Cposting.create!(
    title: title,
    content: content,
    user_id: user_id,
    spots: spots,
    starts_at: starts_at
  ) 
end
```

The migration looks like this, nothing special

```
class AddStartsAtToCpostings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :cpostings, :starts_at, :datetime
  end
end
```

The problem is that starts_at after seeding is nil. Any idea why? Everything else gets inserted without problems. Also if I insert something manually in the database through the form it works, too.

Comment: `DateTime.now` plus 1 what? Plus `1.day` perhaps? They may be the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Just use:

```
starts_at = Time.now
```

or,

```
starts_at = Time.now + 1
```

#### Update 1:

You can try this:

Change your migration to be like this:

```
class AddStartsAtToCpostings < ActiveRecord::Migration
    def change_table
      add_column :cpostings, :starts_at, :datetime
    end
end
```

Use `change_table` method instead of `change`.

#### Update 2:

I just tested your migration locally. Your migration works fine and I can create objects from rails console using your migration and schema where `start_at` works fine if I use `Time.now`.

Comment: Try to print all the attributes in the seed file: `puts starts_at : #{starts_at}` like this. Also, print the created object like this: `puts Cposting.create!(...).inspect`. So, it will be printed in the console what is being created. That way, you will be able to see what's in your `starts_at` variable and what's it get when the object is create. Let me know.

Comment: Can you try creating objects from rails console and see if you can set the `starts_at` field successfully?